# Prepared Insert doesn't do anything if ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES is false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So after a whole lot of struggle with PDO I've narrowed down the root of my problem here. When I set the attribute `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to false my insert query runs without error  but does not add an entry into the database table.

However when I run the query through either PhpMyAdmin or with `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to true it executes successfully.

This is causing me some frustration as there should be no good reason why it doesn't work.

Here's the query I directly executed through PhpMyAdmin.

```
INSERT INTO account (guid, displayname, password_hash, password_salt, email, superuser) VALUES (UNHEX('fcfd7f2355f211e5acfd2174e316c493'), 'bob', 'test', 'test', 'test', 1);
```

Here is the relevant secions of code.

```
$db = null;
try
{
    $db = new PDO($pdo_connectionstring, $pdo_username, $pdo_password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    die('[FATAL ERROR] Could not connect to the Database: '.$ex->getMessage());
}

try
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `account` (`guid`, `displayname`, `password_hash`, `password_salt`, `email`, `superuser`) VALUES (UNHEX(:guid), :displayname, :passwordhash, :passwordsalt, :email, :superuser);");

    $stmt->bindValue(':guid', $guid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':displayname', $displayname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':passwordhash', $hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':passwordsalt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':superuser', $superuser, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);

    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    $jsonresult['generalerror'] = 'Failed to create user. Please contact your GM: ' . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0be23) of my database schema, and the version information of the system and components in question

- Debian 6.0.10 running on 1and1's Shared Hosting
- PHP 5.4.44
- MySQL server 5.5.44-0+deb7u1-log

**EDIT:** Credit to @RyanVincent for figuring this out. The first part of this is that my database column `superuser` was defined as a `tinyint(1)` which despite being a common Boolean storage datatype, requires `PDO::PARAM_INT` when binding the value. The second part of this is that when the PDO driver is running with `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` set to `false` it doesn't throw errors or exceptions if the database returns an error message, only when the local PDO driver encounters a problem. `PDOStatement::execute()` returns a Boolean value as to whether the query was successful or not. It is up to the developer to manually check `PDOStatement::errorCode()` and `PDOStatement::errorInfo()` if `execute()` returns false. This is of particular note during transactions as it is important to rollback the transaction if one of the statements fails. An annoying quirk of PDO is that if you set the wrong datatype I.E. `PDO::PARAM_BOOL` instead of `PDO::PARAM_INT` like I did, the returned `errorInfo()` will be pretty much empty, leaving you scratching your head as to what went wrong anyway.

**TL:DR** when setting `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to `false`, use additional error catching and if something isn't working, check and double check your datatypes.

Comment: remove the try .. catch and you will see any error? Hmm, it works here ;-/ PHP 5.3.29, mysql 5..5.16.

Comment: @RyanVincent, Commented out the try/catch and set the ERRMODE to ERRMODE_WARNING. No luck. No errors, no messages, no warnings. By all rights I'm certain it should work as well. Here's what I've got: PHP Version: 5.4.44, MySQL version: 5.5.44-0+deb7u1-log, mysqlnd version: 5.0.10.

Comment: @RyanVincent, Tested it without the try/catch but with the `ERRMODE` set to throw exceptions. I added `error_reporting(E_NOTICE);` to the beginning of the file but nothing was reported besides my json result data (which mistakenly said everything was successful) from the end of the script. I've added a link to a SQLFiddle in my original question.

Comment: @RyanVincent, Thanks, I'll test the above here in a few hours. Thanks for digging through it! Yeah one of my headaches is being on shared hosting that doesn't give me access to the MySQL query logs. Felt like I was shooting in the dark trying to figure it out without that. I'll reply back once I test that, although yeah I guess emulation is the way to go then.

Comment: @RyanVincent, It worked! I edited my question above with the results.

Comment: Alrighty, I've added in the version information. I'll cut my abridged answer section once your answer goes up.

Comment: Interesting, I would be very interested in seeing that once you've got it ready. I'm guessing that's going up with your answer?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that when using `emulate_prepares` as `false` then the query fails and no exception is thrown from `PDO`.

*`TL;DR`* : goto: *Test setup and explanation*

*`TL;DR`* : goto: *The tests and the results*

*`TL;DR`* : goto: *Conclusions*

#### Overview of PDO prepared query processing

The `mysql` driver:

- It does *not* understand `named placeholders`, it only uses `?` to mark the position of `bind variables`.
- Each command returns, if it succeeds - useful information, `false` if it couldn't complete the request.

The result of this is that, when you have `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, it is the responsibility of  `PDO` to convert that to an `Exception`.

Overview of what is expected to happen when a query is executed via `PDO`:

- `prepare`: Query is sent to `PDO` with `named placeholders`.
- `PDO` formats it with '?' and sends it to the `mysql` driver.
- The `mysql` driver sends it the the actual `mysql` server, which processes it, and returns information explaining how it went on back to the `mysql` driver
- The `mysql` driver sends the result back to `PDO`.
- `PDO` examines it and converts it in useful results or `error codes` or `exceptions`, as required.

As can be seen, there are rather more places than we would like, for confusion to happen.

To debug what is happening I wanted to know exactly what the `mysql server` received and what was returned.

To do that, the `mysql server` provides  `general logging for queries` see: [5.2.3 The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html).

I have provided utilities to control switching on and off the `general log` for both writing to `log files` and writing to the `mysql.general_log` table.

Tested code: [`IMysqlGeneralLogging: Control the MySQL General Logging Facility`](http://pastebin.com/mtKqaEEd) and [`class`](http://pastebin.com/iYd8r5sM).

*Debugging and Explaining the actual O/P code:*

I have supplied `PHPUnit` testing scripts to run the O/P code and check things. I am using it as a 'execute and report' tool rather than for testing anything.

This is really explaining what I found out and demonstrating it. It took quite a bit of time and quite a lot of 'trial and error'. With the emphasis being on the 'error'. ;-)

### Test setup and explanation

```
/**
 * Test Data for all tests...
 */
protected $guid             = '420D4B65565311E5958000FFD7CBE75F';
protected $displayname     = 'Example User 42';
protected $hash             = '$2y$17$12345678901234567890121234567890123456789012345678942';
protected $salt             = '$2y$17$1234567890123456789042$';
protected $email            = 'example42@example.com';
protected $superuser       =  true;

/**
 * Expected Results
 * Must be static so they are not reset with each test
 */
protected static $rcExpected = array(
    'prepare'       => true,
    'execute'       => true,
    'exception'     => false,
    'exceptionMsg'  => '',
);

/**
 * Actual results stored in here. 
 */
protected static $rcActual = array(
    'prepare'       => false,
    'execute'       => false,
    'exception'     => false,
    'exceptionMsg'  => '',
);
```

The code used was changed to store results in the above arrays.

```
    // these change for each test...
    $this->userPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->userPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);

    try
    {
        self::$rcActual['exception'] = false;

        $stmt = $this->userPDO->prepare(
                   "INSERT INTO `account`
                            (`guid`,       `displayname`, `password_hash`, `password_salt`, `email`, `superuser`)
                    VALUES
                            (UNHEX(:guid), :displayname,  :passwordhash,   :passwordsalt,   :email,  :superuser);");


        self::$rcActual['prepare'] = $stmt !== false; // record result

        $stmt->bindValue(':guid',         $this->guid,         PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':displayname',  $this->displayname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':passwordhash', $this->hash,         PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':passwordsalt', $this->salt,         PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email',        $this->email,        PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':superuser',    $this->superuser,   PDO::PARAM_BOOL);

        self::$rcActual['execute'] = $stmt->execute(); // record result

        $this->assertTrue(self::$rcActual['execute']);
        $this->assertFalse(self::$rcActual['exception']);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        self::$rcActual['exception'] = true;
        self::$rcActual['exeptionMsg'] = $e->getCode() .' : '. $e->getMessage();
        $this->assertTrue(self::$rcActual['exception']);
    }
```

Code to start the `mysql general logging` to a trace file:

```
    $testFilename = $this->logging->newTraceFilename('Test_01_EmulatesOn_ExceptionOn'));
    $this->logging->setLogFile($testFilename);
    $this->logging->startLoggingToFile(); // start logging...
```

And stop logging to the trace file:

```
    $this->logging->stopLogging();
```

### The tests and the results:

---

#### Test Series 1 - standard PDO (emulates ON):

```
    $this->userPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->userPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

#### Test 1 : All Ok...

Testing Code: [Q32451215Test 01 EmulatesOn_ExpectsAllOk](http://pastebin.com/ikXm9GrN)

Results:

Expected / Actual:

```
prepare   : Expected:  true, Actual: true
execute   : Expected:  true, Actual: true
exception : Expected:  false, Actual: false
exceptionMsg : Expected:  '', Actual: ''
```

Trace Log:

```
150914 14:15:30   569 Query INSERT INTO `account`
                            (`guid`,       `displayname`, `password_hash`, `password_salt`, `email`, `superuser`)
                    VALUES
                            (UNHEX('420D4B65565311E5958000FFD7CBE75F'), 'Example User 42',  '$2y$17$12345678901234567890121234567890123456789012345678942',   '$2y$17$1234567890123456789042$',   'example42@example.com',  1)
```

Note:

- There is **not** a separate `prepare` and `execute` statement sent to the server. Interesting?

---

#### Test Series 2 - PDO (emulates OFF):

#### Test 2A : Same settings as Test 1 except emulates OFF

Testing Code: [Q32451215Test 02A EmulatesOff__WithSuperUserAsBooleanParamType](http://pastebin.com/2vVPf8mM)

Unchanged bind statement:

```
 $stmt->bindValue(':superuser',    $this->superuser,   PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

Results:

Expected / Actual:

```
prepare   : Expected:  true, Actual: true
execute   : Expected:  true, Actual: false
exception : Expected:  false, Actual: false
exceptionMsg : Expected:  '', Actual: ''
errorCode : '00000', ErrorMsg: array (
  0 => '00000',
  1 => NULL,
  2 => NULL,
)
```

Trace Log:

```
150915 11:37:12   693 Prepare   INSERT INTO `account`
                            (`guid`,       `displayname`, `password_hash`, `password_salt`, `email`, `superuser`)
                    VALUES
                            (UNHEX(?), ?,  ?,   ?,   ?,  ?)
```

Notes:

*These are `unexpected`!* ;-/

- The trace log only contains the `prepare statement`!
- There was no `execute` command sent to the server.
- The `PDO execute` statement returned `false` but no `exception` was raised!
- There was no unusual `errorCode` or `errorInfo` message returned.

This indicates that either `PDO` or the `mysql driver` didn't like the 'PDO::PARAM_BOOL` or the actual value supplied to it.

- The only way you can check this `SQL statement` has failed is to check the results returned from the individual `prepare` and `execute` statements! Also, you have no clue why it failed!

This makes debugging *interesting* ;-/

#### Test 2B : Same settings as Test 2A except `PDO::PARAM_INT`

Testing Code: [Q32451215Test 02B EmulatesOff__WithSuperUserAsIntegerParamType](http://pastebin.com/p3mKBbcz)

This is the only change to the code:

```
  $stmt->bindValue(':superuser',    $this->superuser,   PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Results:

Expected / Actual:

```
prepare   : Expected:  true, Actual: true
execute   : Expected:  true, Actual: true
exception : Expected:  false, Actual: false
exceptionMsg : Expected:  '', Actual: ''
errorCode : '00000', ErrorMsg: ''
```

Trace Log:

```
150915 12:06:07   709 Prepare   INSERT INTO `account`
                            (`guid`,       `displayname`, `password_hash`, `password_salt`, `email`, `superuser`)
                    VALUES
                            (UNHEX(?), ?,  ?,   ?,   ?,  ?)

      709 Execute   INSERT INTO `account`
                            (`guid`,       `displayname`, `password_hash`, `password_salt`, `email`, `superuser`)
                    VALUES
                            (UNHEX('420D4B65565311E5958000FFD7CBE75F'), 'Example User 42',  '$2y$17$12345678901234567890121234567890123456789012345678942',   '$2y$17$1234567890123456789042$',   'example42@example.com',  1)
```

Notes:

*These are exactly as expected:*

- The trace log contains the `prepare` and `execute` statements.
- The `PDO execute` statement returned `true`
- There was no unusual `errorCode` or `errorInfo` message returned.

What is odd is that only the `binding paramater` was changed.

### Conclusions

#### standard PDO: Emulates_Prepares ON

`PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` ==> `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

- Exceptions will always be raised on errors.
- Bound parameters will try to be interpreted in a reasonable manner and not cause failures.
- Use this mode normally.

#### standard PDO: Emulates_Prepares OFF

`PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` ==> `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

- **Exceptions will not always be raised**
- Bound parameters will be interpreted exactly as requested.
- This can cause a return of `false` from the `PDO execute` statement.
- This is the only clue that the query has failed.
- **Always** check the **value returned** from `PDO prepare` and `PDO execute` from being **false**.